Looking to solve a puzzle from Ben Drowned called "The Glitch Cipher"
This cipher is from Arc 2 of Ben Drowned, and was visible for only a few minutes on the homepage on October 6, 2010. It has not yet been solved. Boxentriq's Cipher Identifier says the cipher is likely a Monoalphabetic Substitution, but that may not be accurate as the cipher's formatting may have something to do with text groupings, omissions, or even solution methods.
You can view a Wayback Machine version of the page this cipher was on here (do not yet want to rule out the idea that the page's other contents may be relevant to the cipher). Just in case the Wayback Machine is still buggy, here is an image of the ciphertext by itself.
The event called "The Glitch" may be relevant to the solution of the cipher, and so here is a wiki page describing the site this event happened on - the link goes directly to the part referring to the Glitch itself.

Welcome to Puzzling! Please can you edit to include the cipher itself (preferably in text form), so that your question doesn't depend on external links.

You might want to take a look into the source code too. The Wayback Machine adds some stuff though.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to include the formatting of the cipher itself in text form, and do not want to omit it as it could be important to solving it. It requires superscript as well as subscript, and I'm not sure how to do that on this site.
Also cannot look into the source code, as the original page has been gone since 2010 and the wayback machine link is to an archive of the page that was recreated from a screenshot of the Glitch page (original was not archived online - the Glitch was seen on the Homepage of the site for under 30 minutes total, too short a time to archive).
